# count after groupby in Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have the following in my Google cloud storage

```
Advertiser | Event
__________________
100 | Click

101 | Impression

100 | Impression

100 | Impression

101 | Impression
```

My output of the pipeline should be something like

```
Advertiser | Count

100 | 3

101 | 2
```

First I used groupByKey, the output is like

```
100 Click, Impression, Impression

101 Impression, Impression
```

How to proceed from here?

Comment: Please include a relevant snippet of the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2):

This counting pattern has been described in the 'word count' sample of Apache Beam.

Find the sample at [Github apache beam sample: wordcount.py](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py). The counting starts at line 95.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `GroupByKey`, you may want to use a *combine* function, which is a composite that optimizes before and after the group by key. Your pipeline can look something like this:

**Python**

```
collection_contents = [(100, 'Click'), 
                       (101, 'Impression'), 
                       (100, 'Impression'), 
                       (100, 'Impression'), 
                       (101, 'Impression']

input_collection = pipeline | beam.Create(collection_contents)

counts = input_collection | Count.PerKey()
```

This should output a collection with the shape you are looking for. The `Count` series of transforms is available in the `apache_beam.transforms.combiners.combine.Count` module.

**Java**

The same transforms exist for Java in the `org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms` package:

```
PCollection<KV<Integer, Integer>> resultColl = inputColl.apply(Count.perKey())
```